# How to read application.conf file into databricks?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, config, databricks

I am having a application.conf file in ADLS GEN-2. I was trying to read the file into databricks by mounting the container. I was doing below and file is not begin read.

```
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}                                                                                          
val fileConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("dbfs:/mnt/configs/application.conf"))
val appConfig = ConfigFactory.load(fileConfig).getConfig("HeNAppConf").getConfig(s"$env")
```

I am getting error like : No configuration setting found for key 'HeNAppConf'. But I am having

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ConfigFactory` class should work only with local file APIs, so it doesn't understand `dbfs:` style of paths.  But you can access data via [local file API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#local-file-apis) if you replace `dbfs:` with `/dbfs`, like this:

```scala
import com.typesafe.config.{Config, ConfigFactory}
val fileConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(
  new File("/dbfs/mnt/configs/application.conf"))
```